# How to print the count of the match (nth match) in the substituted string in a find-replace regexp on a string in a stream using either sed or perl?

Tags: regex, perl, sed

Details:

I am reading a file in an incoming stream using tail -f

I am able to find and replace characters/strings in the stream using sed, something like:

```
tail -f a.log | sed 's/'`echo -e "\xnn"`'/'`echo "$(tput setaf 1)|sep|$(tput sgr0)"`'/g'
```

What the above achieves is give me a clear visual marker for the separator string (which is non-printable hex character nn in this case, nn might be 05 as an example, replacing it with a red (in this case) colored (via tput) string |sep|.

So I get something like

```
field **|sep|** field **|sep|** field **|sep|**
```

What I want is

```
field **|sep#1|** field **|sep#2|** field **|sep#3|**
```

So, the requirement is to have the nth match marked as such in the substitution string (|sepn| where n is the no. of match encountered)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Perl's ability to evaluate replacement on the fly to keep track of number of replacements made:

```
my $str='field **|sep|** field **|sep|** field **|sep|**';
my $str2='saodifuasd|sep|psaoidugfsdoif|sep|sdoiufd';
my $cnt;
$cnt=0; $str=~s/\|sep\|/"|sep#".$cnt++."|"/ge;
$cnt=0; $str2=~s/\|sep\|/"|sep#".$cnt++."|"/ge;
print "$str\n";
print "$str2\n";
```

Result:

```
field **|sep#0|** field **|sep#1|** field **|sep#2|**
saodifuasd|sep#0|psaoidugfsdoif|sep#1|sdoiufd
```

As you see, you will have to manually reset separator counter on every line.

Comment: that works, except that I am now struggling to find a way to embed color information in the substitution string...

Comment: I decided to do what I had wanted to avoid, which is splitting the input, so I could add separator in different color using print colored in between printing the fields obtained via split.

Comment: Using Term::ANSIColor? Why not just insert "colored" function inside regexp evaluation part? It simply generates color escape codes. You don't need to print them right away.

Comment: I had tried it earlier today, didn't work if I remember correctly (but I am very forgetful)

Comment: I tried it again today as advised (use colored function in the substitution string and it works); so yesterday, might have been doing it differently (can't recall what I was doing wrong)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether this helps, its in (g)awk.

```
gawk -F 'sep' '{ a=1;while (a <= NF) {printf("%d:%s",a,$a); a++}print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    #! /usr/bin/perl
    #sed 's/'`echo -e "\x05"`'/'`echo "$(tput setaf 1)|sep|$(tput sgr0)"`'/g'
    use warnings;
    use strict;
    use Term::ANSIColor;
    use Term::ANSIColor qw(:constants);

    while(<>) {
    my $count=1;
    #s/\x05/"|#".$count++."|"/ge;
    s/\x05/colored("|#".$count++."|", 'RED')/ge;
    print;
    }
```